# How to reverse the output of the grep command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

i have one problem with grep command. in my called script i use:

```
   "ServicePassword":fooooooooooo
   "ServiceUserName":barrrrrrrrr
grep -E '"ServiceUserName"|"ServicePassword"' >> user.txt
```

but in user.txt file i will get first "ServicePassword":fooooooooooo then "ServiceUserName":barrrrrrrrr 
How can i use grep command to reverse it to get first ServiceUserName then ServicePassword output in user.txt file ? I need it only this sequence. i try to change:

```
grep -E '""ServicePassword""|"ServiceUserName"' >> user.txt
```

and nothing.... maybe exist a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grep just filters, `man grep` : `print lines matching a pattern`, to change order another tool must be used, as there's only two items maybe adding `|sort` or `|sort -r` (sort reverse) can help.

```
grep -E '"ServiceUserName"|"ServicePassword"' | sort -r >> user.txt
```

Comment: It works, but it is slow on big files because you sort after grep

Comment: @sebadagostino, thank you for your comment, can you explain what you mean on big files sort would be faster before grep ?

Comment: Hi Nahuel, I didn't mean say that sorting before greping would be faster. I did grep + sort on a big log file and it took a very long time because it takes a long time to do the sorting after doing the whole grep. I think it works, but if I were to use it more often, I would dig into a more performing solution.

Comment: as i said in the answer that sort could be used in this particular case because there were only two items. other answers are not much more perfmormant they need to read the whole file which is the most expensive

Comment: an optimization could be to read line by line and to stop once the two pattern are found in one command `perl -ne '$pwd=$_ if/"ServicePassword"/;$user=$_ if/"ServiceUserName"/;exit print$user.$pwd if$user&&$pwd'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use and adapt the [tac command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/tac.htm) below:

```
$ cat test.txt
"ServicePassword":fooooooooooo
"ServiceUserName":barrrrrrrrr

$ egrep '"ServicePassword"|"ServiceUserName"' test.txt | tac
"ServiceUserName":barrrrrrrrr
"ServicePassword":fooooooooooo
```

Comment: no need to start with `cat test.txt` - just `egrep '"ServicePassword"|"ServiceUserName"' test.txt | tac > user.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use `tac` (opposite of `cat`)

```sh
grep -E '"ServiceUserName"|"ServicePassword"' | tac >> user.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '/ServicePassword/{pwd=$0};/ServiceUserName/{user=$0};
     END{printf pwd; print user}'
```